# Procedure mysql in pentaho

Tags: mysql, pentaho, dashboard

I write procedure mysql in CDE dashboard query with our put param like this is corect ?

```
if ${colum}=1
select ordernumber,productcode from orderfact
else
select ordernumber,productcode,priceeach,totalprice from orderfact
```

${colum} is my param

Answer (score 0):

no. The query in CDA is just a query which is SQL and can be paramaterised.

instead you could do this:

```
select ordernumber, productcode, case when colum=1 then null else priceeach end
```

etc..

Altho its a pretty odd thing to be doing. can you explain your use case?